Is it a good practice to send authentication info every time I request Wordpress API?
I have a Wordpress web site and I am using its APIs to build a mobile application.
Some of them require authentication and others don't
I want help. should I send username and password with every request, or just send it once?
And if once, how can I guarantee the API user would still be logged in?

You will need to send some form of authentication for every request that requires authentication, otherwise that request won’t be authenticated.

I would make it a practice always to send authentication. For one thing, that’s how REST was designed. For another, some endpoints send different results to unauthenticated clients, and debugging will be easier if you don’t need to contend with that.
